# Open Source Glassfish 3.1.1 and clustering

Tags: glassfish-3, cluster-computing

I want to tests running web application on cluster to get information about perfomance. I've created cluster with two nodes. I've also deployed application on 2 nodes, and in administration panel GlassFish displays IPs for nodes, from which I can get acces to application.

Cluster info page gives information about:

```
Multicast Port: 2048
Multicast Address: 228.9.3.1
```

but if I type given address and port resources aren't found. I changed this values to my host IP and port, but the problem is the same.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I do something more to set up cluster IP and port?

Answer (score 1):

In order to configure your clusters ports you should check the instance properties.

Here´s the path:

```
Clusters -> <your cluster name> -> Instances -> <your instance name> -> Properties
```

And then change to values you want.